# Misunderstanding the use of 'apply'

Tags: r

I have a function:

```
myFun <- function (x, y)
{
}
```

It's intended to process a column of a dataframe

```
myFun(dataFrame$Column, anotherPrameterValue)
```

dataFrame$Column is a Factor with 4 levels. It's well recognized by the function and works great. I attach image of environment data from debugger (breakpoint inside the function, the first line)

[image]

It also works if passed by index:

```
myFun(dataFrame[1], anotherPrameterValue)
```

[image]

But, if I code:

```
apply(dataFrame, 2, myFun, y = anotherParameterValue)
```

The data passed to the function in 'x' is very different:

[image]

I suppose it must be something I'm not understanding in 'apply'...

If you need the code inside my function, tell me, but I think it's not neccesary, as the problem shows in the data received through parameters.

Comment: The base function `apply` converts your input to a matrix. It does not work natively with data.frames. That's why it's often not a good idea to use `apply` with data.frames; especially when you have columns of mixed types. It would be better to map functions over those columns. It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: `apply` works on matrices.  It will coerce your dataframe to a matrix, which forces everything to be the same type.  BTW, you shouldn't post images of data; they are impossible for others to work with.  Simplify your data, and then post the result of `dput(dataFrame)` so others can run it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in the comments, `apply` is for objects of class `matrix`. R will happily/silently try to convert your frame input to a matrix while doing so.

A working example:

```r
set.seed(42)
quux <- data.frame(int1=sample(1000,3), int2=sample(1000,3), num3=runif(3), num4=runif(3)) |>
  transform(fctr5 = factor(int1), chr6=as.character(int2))
quux
#   int1 int2      num3      num4 fctr5 chr6
# 1  561  153 0.7365883 0.7050648   561  153
# 2  997   74 0.1346666 0.4577418   997   74
# 3  321  228 0.6569923 0.7191123   321  228
myfun <- function(z, y = 0) y + mean(z)
myfun(quux$int2, 1000)
# [1] 1151.667
apply(quux, 2, myfun, y = 1000)
# Warning in mean.default(z) :
#   argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
# Warning in mean.default(z) :
#   argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
# Warning in mean.default(z) :
#   argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
# Warning in mean.default(z) :
#   argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
# Warning in mean.default(z) :
#   argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
# Warning in mean.default(z) :
#   argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
#  int1  int2  num3  num4 fctr5  chr6 
#    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
```

If we debug `myfun` and step into what's going on, we'll immediately see a problem:

```r
debug(myfun)
apply(quux, 2, myfun, y = 1000)
# debugging in: FUN(newX[, i], ...)
# debug at #1: y + mean(z)
y
# [1] 1000
z
# [1] "561" "997" "321"
```

You can `c`ontinue through each call to `myfun`, once per column. You'll find that they are all class `character`.

It seems "obvious" that one cannot calculate something on the strings, and sometimes some math-operations can work on `factor`s (not with `mean`) but they *shouldn't* (because depending on the function, it might work on the `integer`-encoding of the factor or the string-representations of the levels, very different things).

How do we fix this? Subset the frame so that you're only operating on the number-like columns.

```r
isnum <- sapply(quux, is.numeric)
isnum
#  int1  int2  num3  num4 fctr5  chr6 
#  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE 
apply(quux[,isnum], 2, myfun, y = 1000)
#     int1     int2     num3     num4 
# 1626.333 1151.667 1000.509 1000.627
```

FYI, `apply` itself is not necessary, we can also use `lapply` or `sapply` here, depending on what you're planning on doing with the return value. For example, if you just need the averages as above, use

```r
sapply(quux[,isnum], myfun, y = 1000)
#     int1     int2     num3     num4 
# 1626.333 1151.667 1000.509 1000.627
```

But if you want to replace the frames values (for some reason ... work with me), one might do:

```r
quux[isnum] <- lapply(quux[isnum], myfun, y = 1000)
quux
#       int1     int2     num3     num4 fctr5 chr6
# 1 1626.333 1151.667 1000.509 1000.627   561  153
# 2 1626.333 1151.667 1000.509 1000.627   997   74
# 3 1626.333 1151.667 1000.509 1000.627   321  228
```

Or if you wanted to *append* the columns to `quux`, then

```r
# (starting with the original quux)
isnum_ch <- names(isnum)[isnum]
isnum_ch <- paste0(isnum_ch, "_new")
isnum_ch
# [1] "int1_new" "int2_new" "num3_new" "num4_new"
cbind(quux, setNames(lapply(quux[isnum], myfun, y = 500), isnum_ch))
#   int1 int2      num3      num4 fctr5 chr6 int1_new int2_new num3_new num4_new
# 1  561  153 0.7365883 0.7050648   561  153 1126.333 651.6667 500.5094 500.6273
# 2  997   74 0.1346666 0.4577418   997   74 1126.333 651.6667 500.5094 500.6273
# 3  321  228 0.6569923 0.7191123   321  228 1126.333 651.6667 500.5094 500.6273
```

Comment: Thanks! The solution was using 'lapply' :)